# Prove an inequality envolving $L^{1}$ and $L^{2}$ norms: $||f||_1 \le ||f||_2 ?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

I want to prove the following:

The uniform, $L^1$ and $L^2$ norms on $C([0,1])$ satisfy

$$||f||_1 \le ||f||_2 \le ||f||_u$$

The thing is How Can I prove that

$$||f||_1 \le ||f||_2 ?$$

Note: $ ||f||_u=max_{x \in[0,1]}|f(x)|$

Comment: Holder.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Can you post how to manipulate it to have the desire inequelity please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: write $|f| = |f| \cdot 1$ and apply Holder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For $f \in C([0,1])$, how can I prove that 
>   $$||f||_1 \le ||f||_2 ?$$

**Hint.** [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality):
$$
\left|\int_{[0,1]}fdx\right|\leq \int_{[0,1]}1\times\left|f\right|dx\leq\left(\int_{[0,1]}1^2\:dx\right)^{1/2}\times\left(\int_{[0,1]}\left|f\right|^2dx\right)^{1/2}
$$

Comment: Is it staight foward with this ?

Comment: @user162343 I give you some details.

Comment: Please is because I am realy tired with this theorem jajajaj

Comment: @user162343 $f=gf{}{}{}{}{}$ if $g=1$.

Comment: Ok let me try it. Just give some time because I am going to a conference, so give some minutes please :), dont disconnect :)

Comment: @user162343 See my edit. Thanks!

Comment: Well Is done right?